# static external IP for azure hosts

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I am creating an Azure Virtual Desktop implementation. What is the correct way to make sure that the AVD's use a static IP address for outgoing connections?

Is it by creating a NAT Gateway?

Comment: Why not use DNS?

Comment: No, this is for outbound purposes. For example, a user logged in to an Azure Virtual Desktop session accesses a web app. I want to whitelist the IP address the user is presenting, so I need that IP address to be static.

Comment: I would suggest adding that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the outbound IP then there are several different methods to ensure traffic from an Azure vNet uses a consitent IP, pick the one that works best for you:

- Assigning a Public IP to the VM, which will be used for outbound traffic. Probably not workable for AVD
- Put VMs behind an Azure load balancer and use the outbound rules to define outbound IP
- Azure vNet NAT Gateway - defines a static outbound IP for all traffic on a vnet, probably the simplest option for your scenario
- Azure Firewall (or other FW device) - all traffic is routed out the firewall, and will use this as the outbound IP.

See [here](https://samcogan.com/obtaining-a-static-outbound-ip-from-an-azure-virtual-network/) for more details.